# unable to locate element in new tab chrome - Selenium Webdriver with java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When clicking the menu in the application, it automatically opens that page in a new tab, then do the action in the new tab

```
String mainWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();

//when click the below its opened in new tab
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.slds-align-middle")).click();
Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
for (String handle : handles) {
    if (!handle.equals(mainWindow)) {
        driver.switchTo().window(handle);
        break;
    }
}

driver.findElement(By.id("23:311;a")).click();
```

After switching to the new window unable to locate the element

```
driver.findElement(By.id("23:311;a"))
```

How can I click the element in the newly opened tab?

HTML:
This is salesforce application

```
<span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-new-window slds-m-left--x-small focus-icon" data-aura-rendered-by="54:375;a">
```

Comment: I very much doubt the id is  `23:311;a`. Please share the html.

Comment: Sometimes selenium is faster than your browser. try a timeout (Thread.sleep(500);), maybe this helps.

Comment: Thread.sleep also not working

Comment: @Prabu provided HTML doesn't contains any id attribute. Are you sure provided HTML is correct???

Answer (score 0):

`23:311;a` is not ID attribute, it `data-aura-rendered-by` attribute and it seems to be random so you can't really relay on that to locate the element. I suggest you use unique class name. `lds-icon-utility-new-window` seems unique enough

```
driver.findElement(By.className("lds-icon-utility-new-window"));
```

Or combination of several class attributes

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".slds-icon_container.slds-icon-utility-new-window"));
```

Comment: Thanks Guy: will check my xpath